@vite directive causes error after build with laravel vite
Previewing the page looks fine while running on "npm run dev".
Then, I ran "npm run build", no error in command line and everything looks fine. However when I preview the page, it now shows this
ERROR : Array to string conversion
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title>Document</title>



    @vite(['resources/scss/app.scss'], ['resources/js/app.js'])   // error here

</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>



The @vite() directive takes an array of paths as a parameter, while you're passing multiple parameters to it.
The correct way to do this would be:
@vite(['resources/scss/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'])

